# how to join two table in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table persons and order. I needto join these two tables.

```
$sql=mysql_query("select id from users");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sq))
  {
   $id=$row['id']

  }
```

now using this dynamic id I want to join table persons and order

table persons.

```
id  LastName    FirstName   Address     
1   Hansen      Timoteivn   Sandnes
2   Svendson    Tove        Sandnes
3   Pettersen   Kari        Stavanger
```

table orders

```
  id    orders  OrderNo
    1   y   1256
    2   n   11251
    2   m   5555
```

Comment: This looks like a schoolbook question. -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to on this URL and read it

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

I think it is very helpful to understanding join in SQL...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `orders` USING (`id`);
```